# How to turn machine code into binary executable?

Tags: assembly, compilation, compiler-construction, linker, x86

I'm writing a very small x86 assembler which currently outputs hex (or binary, it'd be trivial to change) machine code. How can I write this hex/binary into a file that I can actually execute?

For a simple input like:

```
mov ax, #1
ret
```

the assembler would output:

```
66b80100
c3
```

Comment: You'll need to learn about the structure of the executable file format(s) required by the platform you're using, and create a file in such a format. One of the things it will contain is your assembled machine instructions.

Comment: And you have another major choice to make: will you write object files and link them with an existing linker, or are you writing your own linker (or integrating the functionality of the linker into the assembler, possibly limiting the program to a single source file?)

Comment: Change the output of your assembler so it outputs something like `DB 066h, 0b8h, 001h, 000h` or `.byte 0x66, 0xb8, 0x01, 0x00` and assemble it with an assembler like MASM or the GNU Assembler, and then link the resulting object file to create an executable.

Comment: @RossRidge what file format is that header for?

Comment: It's not a header, it's a translation of the first line your example output into MASM and GNU Assembler syntax respectively. You'd need a bit more than so it all assembles correctly, but hopefully you know what that is because you've used an assembler before.

Comment: @RossRidge oops! My mistake. Do you know what else I could try besides just placing the output of my assembler into a different assembler?

Comment: Pick an operating system (eg. Windows or Linux), and then learn its executable and related object file file format as the first two comments suggested. Windows' format is called PECOFF, Linux's is called ELF, and OS X is called Mach-O. It's not as easy as prefixing the output with a simple header.

Comment: See [this article / tutorial](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) on making tiny executables.  The goal there is different, but it introduces the concept of the structure of an executable file.  In your case, DOS COM files are pretty much (or literally?) flat binary files with no metadata that get loaded into memory and run.  All other executable file format have headers.

Comment: object files would allow you to use any other linker on the platform you are using and mix with many other languages. But if this is just some small project for fun, why not to start with old DOS .com, which is flat binary up to 64ki bytes. Then the DOS .exe should be quite trivial too (at least some very early version, without win16/32 extended header stuff).

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the link! I used the ELF header provided by that article and compiled with nasm, then opened the binary with a hex editor. How would I turn this hex (or corresponding binary) back into an executable?

Comment: That binary *is* an executable.  That's the whole point; to assemble bytes into a file such that it's an ELF executable.

Comment: @PeterCordes Right, I understand that. I meant if I had _just_ the hex, as my assembler currently outputs. If I directly pipe the bytes into a file, `file` tells me it's still seen as plain ASCII, even after marking it as executable. I'm just trying to figure out how to execute a file containing the bytes.

Comment: @Phillip: You seem to be confused between a binary file and a text file containing a hexdump.  Of course you can't execute a hexdump of an ELF binary.  You can hex "undump" with [`xxd -r`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) for example.  See this [Linux Journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/doing-reverse-hex-dump) for a walk-through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append hex values to a binary in C++, you have to represent it as its raw int value and write that to the file.

Thus:

```
void writeHexStringToFile(string hex, ofstream& file) {
    vector<string> hexBytes = hexBytesFromString(hex);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < hexBytes.size(); i++) {
        istringstream buff(hexBytes.at(i));
        int hexVal;
        buff >> hex >> hexVal;
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&hexVal), sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python which is easier than C++ for this case you don't need anything else powerful at low-level.

```
import sys
string = open(sys.argv[1],'r').read()
sys.stdout.write(string.decode("hex"))
```

Put this into a .py file and run it with python file.py [file with hex]

But first of all replace the newlines. You can use

```
cat file.hex | tr -d '\n' > file2.hex
```

Or python